# Android M downloadprovider download fail SecurityException

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-download-manager

E/DownloadManager( 8228): [1] Failed: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10004 nor current process has android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS.
E/DownloadManager( 8228): java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10004 nor current process has android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS.
E/DownloadManager( 8228):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
E/DownloadManager( 8228):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
E/DownloadManager( 8228):    at android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireWakeLock(IPowerManager.java:365)
E/DownloadManager( 8228):    at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquireLocked(PowerManager.java:1119)
E/DownloadManager( 8228):    at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire(PowerManager.java:1087)
E/DownloadManager( 8228):    at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.run(DownloadThread.java:238)
E/DownloadManager( 8228):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
E/DownloadManager( 8228):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/DownloadManager( 8228):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
E/DownloadManager( 8228):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
E/DownloadManager( 8228):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
D/DownloadManager( 8228): [2] Finished with status UNKNOWN_ERROR

W/DownloadManager( 8228): Uncaught exception
W/DownloadManager( 8228): java.lang.SecurityException: NetworkPolicy: Neither user 10004 nor current process has android.permission.CONNECTIVITY_INTERNAL.
W/DownloadManager( 8228):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
W/DownloadManager( 8228):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
W/DownloadManager( 8228):    at android.net.INetworkPolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.unregisterListener(INetworkPolicyManager.java:379)
W/DownloadManager( 8228):    at android.net.NetworkPolicyManager.unregisterListener(NetworkPolicyManager.java:160)
W/DownloadManager( 8228):    at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.run(DownloadThread.java:330)
W/DownloadManager( 8228):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
W/DownloadManager( 8228):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/DownloadManager( 8228):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/DownloadManager( 8228):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/DownloadManager( 8228):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: pms can not find this permission when parse android.media (shareduserid)

Comment: this cause by shareduid, other app use same shareduid android.media android define those permissions in AndroidManifest
 PMS revoke those permission, android can not find it in /data/system/packages.xml

Answer (score 1):

from API level 23 you have to [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request).

Comment: android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS is not runtime Permission

Comment: have you added in manifest ?

Comment: the permission is not for 3rd app, is defined in DownloadProvider,